# Integral of Wiener Process and Central Limit Theorem

Tags: probability, probability-theory, stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus, stochastic-integrals

I am trying to solve the following exercise:

> (1) Given $W$ is a Wiener process, find a constant $M$ such that
>   $\lim\limits_{t\to\infty} \frac{1}{t}\int_{0}^{t}\sin^2W_s ds=M$
>
> (2) Then show that
>   $\frac{1}{\sqrt{t}}\int_{0}^{t}(\sin^2W_s-M) ds$ converges to $N(0,\sigma^2)$ and compute $\sigma^2$.

So far I have only started the first part of the question before getting stumped.  I started the following:
I simply integrated by parts with respect to s and evaluated at the bounds 0 and t

$$\lim_{t\to\infty} \frac{1}{t}\int_{0}^{t}\sin^2W_s ds= \lim_{t\to\infty} \frac{1}{t}\left(\frac{1}{2}\Big((W_t-\sin(W_t)\cos(W_t)-(W_0-\sin(W_0)\cos(W_0)\Big)-\int_{0}^{t}sd(\sin^2W_s)\right)$$

Given $W_0=0$ We have the following:

$$\lim_{t\to\infty} \frac{1}{t}\left(\frac{1}{2}(W_t-\sin(W_t)\cos(W_t))-\int_{0}^{t}sd(\sin^2W_s)\right)$$

I am assuming I have to apply something like Ito's formula to the stochastic integral term on the RHS. However, I am stumped how to show this limit equals a constant M, and how to begin the second part of the problem statement.

Comment: Did I make a mistake in my initial statement with the integration?  Should I be integrating by parts? Hence producing a stochastic integral term.  How can you go about computing limit of $\frac{W_t}{t}$?

Comment: I've edited my answer. For the limit of $\frac{W_t}{t}$, you may consider the integer part $[t]$ of $t$ and show that $W_{[t]} - W_t$ is negligeable when $t$ goes to infinity

Comment: @NicoDean You modified $$\int_{0}^{t}sd(\sin^2W_s)\quad\text{into}\quad\int_{0}^{t}ds(\sin^2W_s).$$ This is probably **not** what the OP intended.

Comment: @Did oh, oops. Then I missed the point of the OPs question; it looked like a typo to me. i'm not familiar about what "sd" should mean in that case. if you understand what the question should have been, could you please correct it? thx.

Comment: @NicoDean I suggest that you revert the modification I unambiguously described.

Comment: @Did ok done (hope it gets accepted soon). In the meantime, can you explain me the meaning of the "sd", even though the OP starts with $\lim_{t\to\infty} \frac{1}{t}\int_{0}^{t}\sin^2W_s ds$

Comment: @NicoDean I guess with $sd(\sin^2 W_s)$ OP means $s\cdot d(\sin^2 W_s)$

Comment: @NicoDean The mention by the OP that they integrate by parts makes the answer to your question rather obvious.

Answer (score 3):

Firstly, by the strong law of large number, the limit should exist.

Consider $$\theta_k = \inf\{t\geq \theta_{k-1}, |W_t- W_{\theta_{k-1}}| = \pi\}, \theta_0 = 0$$
Then the integral can be written as the sum of $\int_{\theta_{k}}^{\theta_{k+1}}\sin^2(W_s)ds$, we have

\begin{align}
\frac{1}{t}\int_0^t \sin^2(W_s)ds = \dfrac{\sum_{k=1}^{+\infty}1_{\theta_k < t}}{t} \dfrac{\sum_{k=0}^{+\infty}\int_{\theta_{k}}^{\theta_{k+1}}\sin^2(W_s)ds1_{\theta_{k+1} < t} + \int_{\theta_{k+1}}^t \sin^2(W_s)ds1_{\theta_{k+1} < t \leq  \theta_{k+2}} }{\sum_{k=1}^{+\infty}1_{\theta_k < t}}
\end{align}

Remark that $$\dfrac{\sum_{k=0}^{+\infty}\int_{\theta_{k}}^{\theta_{k+1}}\sin^2(W_s)ds1_{\theta_{k+1} < t} + \int_{\theta_{k+1}}^t \sin^2(W_s)ds1_{\theta_{k+1} < t \leq  \theta_{k+2}} }{\sum_{k=1}^{+\infty}1_{\theta_k < t}}\to E\int_0^{\theta_1}\sin^2(W_s)ds$$ alomst surely by the strong law of large number because $\int_{\theta_{k}}^{\theta_{k+1}}\sin^2(W_s)ds$'s are i.i.d.

And that $$\dfrac{\sum_{k=1}^{+\infty}1_{\theta_k < t}}{t} \to \dfrac{1}{E(\theta_1)}$$ alomost sutrly(Imagine a Poisson process which jumps once a new $\theta_k$ is reached)

So the limit is equal to $\dfrac{E\int_0^{\theta_1}\sin^2(W_s)ds}{E(\theta_1)}$. To compute it, let $$I_1 = \frac{1}{t}\int_0^t \sin^2(W_s)ds$$ $$I_2 = \frac{1}{t}\int_0^t \cos^2(W_s)ds$$ then we have $I_1 + I_2 = 1$.

Intuitively, when $t\to \infty$, the limit of $I_1$ and $I_2$ should be the same, since $\sin^2 x$  is just $\cos^2 x$ delayed by $\frac{\pi}{2}$, so we get $M = \frac{1}{2}$.

To prove it rigorously, let $\tau = \inf\{t \geq 0, W_t = \frac{\pi}{2}\}$, then 
\begin{align}
I_2 &= \frac{1}{t} \left(\int_0^\tau \cos^2(W_s)ds + \int_{\tau}^t\cos^2(W_s)ds\right) \\
& = \frac{1}{t} \left(\int_0^\tau \cos^2(W_s)ds + \int_{\tau}^t\sin^2(W_s - \frac{\pi}{2})ds\right)
\end{align}

Since $\tau$ is finite almost surely: $$\lim I_2 = \lim \frac{1}{t} \int_{\tau}^t\sin^2(W_s - \frac{\pi}{2})ds = \lim \frac{1}{t} \int_{0}^{t-\tau}\sin^2(W_s')ds = \lim I_1$$
where $W_s' = W_{s+ \tau} - \frac{\pi}{2}$

So the limit of $I_1$ and $I_2$ are both equal to $\frac{1}{2}$

Once the first part is finished, we can realize that we can treat the problem as a renewal process, which jumps once a new $\theta_k$ is reached and with the jump size $\int_{\theta_{k-1}}^{\theta_k}\sin^2(W_s)ds$. Therefore we can apply the central limit theorem for renewal process to resolve the second question.

Comment: How can I compute the variance of the compound poisson process to answer the 2nd part of the second question?

Comment: @user75514 this could be found in a description about the CLT of CPP, for example, [here](http://www.columbia.edu/~ww2040/6711F12/lect0927.pdf) or [here](http://mathoverflow.net/questions/169136/compound-poisson-process-and-central-limit-theorem)

Comment: Still a bit lost.  From the Columbia reference, let $N(t)$ be a Poisson process with rate $\lambda$ so that $E[N(t)]=\lambda t$.  Let $X_i$ be iid random variables independent of N, then $D(t)=\sum\limits_{i=1}^{N(t)} X_i, t\ge 0 $ is a compound Poisson process.  This process has $E[D(t)]=\lambda t E[X_1]$ and $Var[D(T)]=\lambda t E [X_1^2]$.  From part (1) we calculated $E[D(t)]$.  So is $\lambda t= \frac{1}{E(\theta_1)}$?  We used the relationship between sine and cosine to compute the entire quantity $\lambda t E[X_1]$.  Do I follow a similar strategy for calculating $\lambda t E [X_1^2]$?

Comment: @user75514 by the first part we have $\lambda = \dfrac{1}{E\theta_1}$, so the variance we are looking for is $\lambda E(X_1^2)$. I spent a while to figure it out but didn't succeed.